# Word Lists of Various Languages

Tags: computational-linguistics, resource-request, online-resources

I was looking for lists of words (preferably txt files) in various languages  I was looking for just lists of words without any additional data spanning as many languages as possible. Thanks

Comment: What should those lists be good for? Please give more details. I assume, without additional data also means "without translation"?

Comment: I was looking for plain text lists of words in various languages, for example `a aardvark abacus ...`

Comment: Only lemmas, or a list of wordforms (including inflected forms)?

Comment: List of wordforms

Answer (score 3):

FAIR have trained word embedding models for hundreds of languages, with the side effect that they have compiled words lists.

Wikipedia only, 300+ languages

[fasttext.cc/docs/en/crawl-vectors.html](https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/crawl-vectors.html) / [github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/blob/master/pretrained-vectors.md](https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/blob/master/pretrained-vectors.md)

Wikipedia + Common Crawl, 157 languages

[fasttext.cc/docs/en/pretrained-vectors.html](https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/pretrained-vectors.html) / 
[github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/blob/master/docs/crawl-vectors.md](https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/blob/master/docs/crawl-vectors.md)

As noted under [*Format*](https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/blob/master/docs/crawl-vectors.md#format), the words are sorted in order of frequency.  They provide Python code, if you do not care about the vector representation then you could use bash to split on space and take only the first column.)

To download them all, get [download.sh](https://github.com/SignalN/ftio/blob/master/ftio/wiki/download.sh) from the [ftio](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ftio/) package:

```
for (( i=1; i<=$#; i++ )); do
    wget -c "https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/fasttext-vectors/wiki.${!i}.zip"
done

# For example:
# ./download.sh bg el ka hy ru fa es fr de it pt ar tr pl ko

# If stopped it will not re-start automatically, but if re-started it will continue from where it stopped.

# Tested on macOS Sierra only.

# Remember to check if there is enough disk space - they are about 4GB each.
```

(For Wikipedia + Common Crawl, change `wiki.${!i}.zip` to `word-vectors-v2/cc.${!i}.300.vec.gz`.)

You can also try Open Data SE.

Comment: Those are huge files.  What is the format of the 'embedding'?

Comment: @aml Every line is `<word> <vector>`, where `<vector>` is 300 numbers separated by spaces.